# set focus in text field when doubleclicking

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I create a directive to set focus in the text field when executing the event doubleclick but it does not work. Please see my CSS, HTML, and JavaScript below. 
I have also tried to use the DOM to get the text field element and set the focus with `element.focus()` but it does not work.

```js
var app=angular.module('todoApp',[])
app.controller('todoListController',function($scope){
    $scope.todoList=[
 {id:1,name:"apprendre angular",completed:false},
 {id:2,name:"apprendre spring",completed:true}
    ];
    
    $scope.destroy=function(index){
 $scope.todoList.splice(index,1);
    }
    $scope.addTodo=function(){
 $scope.todoList.push({name:$scope.newtodo,completed:false});
 $scope.newtodo="";
    }

    $scope.editTodo=function(todo){
 todo.edit=false;
    }

});

app.directive('todoFocus', function todoFocus($timeout) {
    'use strict';

    return function (scope, elem, attrs) {
 scope.$watch(attrs.todoFocus, function (newVal) {
     if (newVal) {
  $timeout(function () {
      elem[0].focus();
  }, 0, false);
     }
 });
    };
});
```

```css
html,
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

button {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 background: none;
 font-size: 100%;
 vertical-align: baseline;
 font-family: inherit;
 font-weight: inherit;
 color: inherit;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 appearance: none;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -moz-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

body {
 font: 14px 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 line-height: 1.4em;
 background: #f5f5f5;
 color: #4d4d4d;
 min-width: 230px;
 max-width: 550px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -moz-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 font-smoothing: antialiased;
 font-weight: 300;
}

button,
input[type="checkbox"] {
 outline: none;
}

.hidden {
 display: none;
}

#todoapp {
 background: #fff;
 margin: 130px 0 40px 0;
 position: relative;
 box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
             0 25px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

#todoapp input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
 font-style: italic;
 font-weight: 300;
 color: #e6e6e6;
}

#todoapp input::-moz-placeholder {
 font-style: italic;
 font-weight: 300;
 color: #e6e6e6;
}

#todoapp input::input-placeholder {
 font-style: italic;
 font-weight: 300;
 color: #e6e6e6;
}

#todoapp h1 {
 position: absolute;
 top: -155px;
 width: 100%;
 font-size: 100px;
 font-weight: 100;
 text-align: center;
 color: rgba(175, 47, 47, 0.15);
 -webkit-text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
 -moz-text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
 text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

#new-todo,
.edit {
 position: relative;
 margin: 0;
 width: 100%;
 font-size: 24px;
 font-family: inherit;
 font-weight: inherit;
 line-height: 1.4em;
 border: 0;
 outline: none;
 color: inherit;
 padding: 6px;
 border: 1px solid #999;
 box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -moz-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

#new-todo {
 padding: 16px 16px 16px 60px;
 border: none;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.003);
 box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.03);
}

#main {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 2;
 border-top: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}

label[for='toggle-all'] {
 display: none;
}

#toggle-all {
 position: absolute;
 top: -55px;
 left: -12px;
 width: 60px;
 height: 34px;
 text-align: center;
 border: none; /* Mobile Safari */
}

#toggle-all:before {
 content: '❯';
 font-size: 22px;
 color: #e6e6e6;
 padding: 10px 27px 10px 27px;
}

#toggle-all:checked:before {
 color: #737373;
}

#todo-list {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
}

#todo-list li {
 position: relative;
 font-size: 24px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;
}

#todo-list li:last-child {
 border-bottom: none;
}

#todo-list li.editing {
 border-bottom: none;
 padding: 0;
}

#todo-list li.editing .edit {
 display: block;
 width: 506px;
 padding: 13px 17px 12px 17px;
 margin: 0 0 0 43px;
}

#todo-list li.editing .view {
 display: none;
}

#todo-list li .toggle {
 text-align: center;
 width: 40px;
 /* auto, since non-WebKit browsers doesn't support input styling */
 height: auto;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 margin: auto 0;
 border: none; /* Mobile Safari */
 -webkit-appearance: none;
 appearance: none;
}

#todo-list li .toggle:after {
 content: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="40" viewBox="-10 -18 100 135"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="none" stroke="#ededed" stroke-width="3"/></svg>');
}

#todo-list li .toggle:checked:after {
 content: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="40" viewBox="-10 -18 100 135"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="none" stroke="#bddad5" stroke-width="3"/><path fill="#5dc2af" d="M72 25L42 71 27 56l-4 4 20 20 34-52z"/></svg>');
}

#todo-list li label {
 white-space: pre-line;
 word-break: break-all;
 padding: 15px 60px 15px 15px;
 margin-left: 45px;
 display: block;
 line-height: 1.2;
 transition: color 0.4s;
}

#todo-list li.completed label {
 color: #d9d9d9;
 text-decoration: line-through;
}

#todo-list li .destroy {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 10px;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 margin: auto 0;
 font-size: 30px;
 color: #cc9a9a;
 margin-bottom: 11px;
 transition: color 0.2s ease-out;
}

#todo-list li .destroy:hover {
 color: #af5b5e;
}

#todo-list li .destroy:after {
 content: '×';
}

#todo-list li:hover .destroy {
 display: block;
}

#todo-list li .edit {
 display: none;
}

#todo-list li.editing:last-child {
 margin-bottom: -1px;
}

#footer {
 color: #777;
 padding: 10px 15px;
 height: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 border-top: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}

#footer:before {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 50px;
 overflow: hidden;
 box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
             0 8px 0 -3px #f6f6f6,
             0 9px 1px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
             0 16px 0 -6px #f6f6f6,
             0 17px 2px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#todo-count {
 float: left;
 text-align: left;
}

#todo-count strong {
 font-weight: 300;
}

#filters {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 left: 0;
}

#filters li {
 display: inline;
}

#filters li a {
 color: inherit;
 margin: 3px;
 padding: 3px 7px;
 text-decoration: none;
 border: 1px solid transparent;
 border-radius: 3px;
}

#filters li a.selected,
#filters li a:hover {
 border-color: rgba(175, 47, 47, 0.1);
}

#filters li a.selected {
 border-color: rgba(175, 47, 47, 0.2);
}

#clear-completed,
html #clear-completed:active {
 float: right;
 position: relative;
 line-height: 20px;
 text-decoration: none;
 cursor: pointer;
 position: relative;
}

#clear-completed:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
}

#info {
 margin: 65px auto 0;
 color: #bfbfbf;
 font-size: 10px;
 text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
 text-align: center;
}

#info p {
 line-height: 1;
}

#info a {
 color: inherit;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: 400;
}

#info a:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
}

/*
 Hack to remove background from Mobile Safari.
 Can't use it globally since it destroys checkboxes in Firefox
*/
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
 #toggle-all,
 #todo-list li .toggle {
  background: none;
 }

 #todo-list li .toggle {
  height: 40px;
 }

 #toggle-all {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
 }
}

@media (max-width: 430px) {
 #footer {
  height: 50px;
 }

 #filters {
  bottom: 10px;
 }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="todo.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>


  </head>
  <body ng-app="todoApp">
    <section id="todoapp" ng-controller="todoListController">
      <header id="header">
 <h1>TodoList</h1>
 <form action="#" id="todo-form" ng-submit="addTodo()">
   <input type="text" id="new-todo" placeholder="Ajouter une tâche" ng-model="newtodo" autocomplete="off" >
 </form>
      </header>

      <section id="main">
  <ul id="todo-list">
   <li   ng-repeat="todo in todoList" ng-class="{completed:todo.completed,editing:todo.edit}" ng-dblclick="todo.edit=true">
     <div class="view">
       <input type="checkbox" class="toggle" ng-model="todo.completed" />
       <label> {{todo.name}}</label>
       <button class="destroy" ng-click="destroy($index)"> </button>
     </div>
     <form action="#" >
       <input class="edit" ng-model="todo.name" ng-blur="editTodo(todo)" todo-focus="todo == true" >
     </form>
   </li> 
 </ul>
 
      </section>
    </section> 

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, running your code, see this:

```
<input class="edit" ng-model="todo.name" ng-blur="editTodo(todo)" todo-focus="todo == true" >
```

This is your element, and you have this watcher in todo-focus directive:

```
scope.$watch(attrs.todoFocus, function (newVal) {
```

You are watching an angular expression: "todo == true", it solves one time as "false", and will never changes this value, so your watcher will not be executed as you want (only 1 time, when the directive is loaded to initialize the watcher)

So, you need to watch a scope variable, if todo is your scope variable try to watch scope.todo.xxx instead of the attribute

Comment: yes correct, the error is in the attribute expression. the correct expression is todo.edit == true

Comment: Yes, it solves the problem, but is more efficient if you watch a variable instead of a result of a expresion, i think that all the digest cycles will check your expression, if you watch a scope variable, the triggers works in a different way, but, as you see, it works